# Can't write class with params as property

Tags: c#, class, properties, parameters

It seems I can't write a class with params as property.
Is there any way to set params property for class?

For a method, I can do this:

```
public static void Method(double x,params double[] k)
{

}
```

I would like a class that takes unknown number of arguments.

class:

```
public class Class
{
    double x;
    params double[] k;
}
```

and to create new object

```
var obj = new Class(1d, 1d, 1d, ...); //
var obj = new Class(1d, new double[] { 1d, 1d, ...}); //this is not comfortable!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to set params property for class?

No, and there is no need. You can make your class constructor accept a `params double[] doubles` and store them inside an array:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}

public class A
{
    private double[] doubles;
    public A(params double[] doubles)
    {
        this.doubles = doubles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> var obj=new Class(1d,new double[]{1d,1d,...});

you need constructor with `params` to create `obj` like this

```
public class Class
{
    double x;
    double[] k;
    public Class(double _x, params double[] _k)
    {
       x=_x; k=_k;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var obj=new Class(1d,1d,1d);
```